# how to create a query for firebaseRecyclerAdapter to show post of users that a user is following

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I need a query for `firebaseRecyclerAdapter` to show post of users that a user is following.

```
post {
    1 {
        post_image: abc
        uploaded_by: a
    }
    2 {
        post_image: def
        uploaded_by: b
    }

}
followers {
    here b and c are following a
    a {
        b: b
        c: c
    }
}
following {
    here a is following b and c
    b {
        a: a
    }
    c {
        a: a
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with loading the children of followers/a, iterating over them and querying the post node where uploaded_by = a, b etc. You should really write some code and post it to show what you've tried.

Comment: i tried to do that but not able to create a query which then can be passed to adapter, it always take the last value of the loop

Answer (score 0):

there isn't direct way to do so you must do some work on your client. i followed [this](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html) article and i was able to implement following feature in my application

Comment: Can you guide me little bit what I should do